# How to use 301 redirect in .htaccess by IP address?

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have transferred the website to different webhosting. Some users see old website since their DNS servers point to old webhosting IP.

How can I alter the .htaccess in the old website to tell their DNS servers that this IP is wrong and they should follow to a new one? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

The DNS server itself does not contact to your webserver at all, therefor it's impossible "to tell their DNS servers that this IP is wrong".

Also, a HTTP redirection to the new IP address will probably not work as expected (named VHosts, etc?). Have your lowered the TTL of the DNS records? If not, do it now...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a subdomain pointing to the new IP address (new.blah.com) and then do your 301 redirect on the old server to point to the new subdomain.  That will get everyone seeing your site until the DNS changes have propagated everywhere.

Comment: Forgot to give you the instruction for redirecting.  Once you have the subdomain in place just add the following to your .htaccess file:

redirect 301 / http://new.blah.com/